# NZEC runtime error for 2 testcases out of 3 in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, runtime-error

I am trying to solve a question on Hackerearth. The competition had ended long time back.

http://www.hackerearth.com/lenskart-hiring-challenge/algorithm/big-p-and-punishment-5/description/

**The Problem Statement**

Big P has become a Physical Education teacher at Hack International School.

Today, the students of class XII have been very indisciplined and he decides to punish them all.

He makes all of the N student (numbered 1 to N ) to stand in a line and asks them to sit down on their knees.

Students know that Big P is a very cruel and sadistic person and students start to sit down themselves when they see a friend sit down.

However, there are always some students who do not follow the trend. Now when Big P sees that happen , he slaps that student and makes him sit down. The same process as above is followed and is stopped when any - one student in the line refuses to sit down by himself.

Given the students that Big P slaps to make them sit down , you need to tell the total no. of students who sat down in that line.

Note: It is not necessary that if A is friend of B then B is also friend of A.

Input Format :
First Line Contains an integer T denoting no of test cases. Each test case begins with a line containing three integers N, F, S where N is the number of students in the line . Next F lines have two integers A and B denoting the friendship between the students A and B. Next S lines have one integer X denoting the student that was slapped by Big P .

Output Format:
For each test case, output a line containing one integer, the total number of students that sit down in that line.

[ T<=10 , N ,F , S <=10000 ]

Sample Input

1

3 2 1

1 2

2 3

2

Sample Output

2

I have written a Java Code for the same.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Arrays;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")



class Graph
{

static int visited[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{



BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 


int testcases;

int N,F,S,n;

int a,b;

testcases=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

while(--testcases>=0)
{

String[] s = br.readLine().split(" ");  

N=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);

F=n=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);

S=Integer.parseInt(s[2]);



visited=new int[N+1];

Arrays.fill(visited,0);

ArrayList[] adj=new ArrayList[N+1];

while(--n>=0)
{


s = br.readLine().split(" ");  

a=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);

b=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);




if(adj[a]==null){

adj[a]=new ArrayList<Integer>();

}

(adj[a]).add(b);


}


int root;

for(int i=1;i<=S;i++)
{

root=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

dfs(adj,root);

}

int ans=0;

for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
{

if(visited[i]==1){

++ans;

}

}

System.out.println(ans);


}

}


static void dfs(ArrayList adj[],int r)
{

int curr;

if(visited[r]!=1)
{



ArrayList base=adj[r];


if(base!=null)
{


Iterator itr=base.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{

curr=(int)itr.next();

if(visited[curr]==0)
{

dfs(adj,curr);
}

}

}

visited[r]=1;
//System.out.println(r);

}

}

}
```

It passes for the 1st testcase,but gives an NZEC error for the remaining testcases.

I tried making changes like :

1. Used Scanner instead of Stream Reader.
2. Removing static arrays

None of these is helping.

Please help me out in identifying the fault.

Comment: This question should be asked in code review...

Comment: And please explain what tou are trying to do and what is the problem clearly...and I think you are getting NZEC maybe because the variable ans is of type int and constraint maybe of higher range...so try using long

Comment: Constraints fall within int ranges.